# Tensor product preserves quasi-isomorphisms

Tags: homological-algebra, differential-graded-algebras

Let $A, B$ be dg Lie algebras. I'm trying to prove that if $f: A \rightarrow B$ is a quasi-isomorphism then $\otimes^n f: A^{\otimes n} \rightarrow B^{\otimes n}$ is also a quasi-isomorphism. I'm willing to assume that we are working over a field $K$ of characteristic zero, and that $A$ and $B$ are bounded (only nonvanishing positive degrees), if we need to. I think it is enough to prove it for the case $n = 2$, and for that I was trying to show that the mapping cone of $f \otimes f$ is acyclic using the fact that $f$ is a quasi-iso, but I haven't managed to conclude anything from it yet.

I'm new to homological algebra so I think I might be missing some key fact that would make concluding this proof much easier, so I would appreciate if someone could nudge me in the right direction (maybe some reference). Thank you!

Comment: What are $A,B?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry, I forgot to say. I was thinking about them as dg Lie algebras, but the algebra structure here shouldn't matter, so just dg vector spaces. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Over a field everything is flat, so $\otimes$ is exact. From there it's just a hard slog to check the Koszul tensor product inherits this.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thank you for the comment. I don't have much experience in homological algebra, do you mind just giving an overview of what the "hard slog" entails? I think this is what I'm confused about.

Comment: Lots of boring calculations. I’m sure it’s in any textbook, possibly after spectral sequences are introduced (but I’m sure they aren’t needed…).